# vim folding - how to copy unfolded lines

Tags: unix, vim, vim-plugin

I would like to copy/delete all the lines except the folded lines and vice-versa. How do I do that?
It is ok if I have to use a plugin for that as well. But, I would love to have that functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:folddoopen y W
```

yanks every non-folded line into register `w`. `W` is used to append to register `w`.

```
:folddoopen d
```

deletes every non-folded line.

There's of course a mirror command, `:folddoclose` that acts on every folded line.